# making a random paired vector from another single vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

```
    // attender list, PID
    std::vector<DWORD> m_vec_attender{1111, 1112, 1113, 1114, 1115, 1116, 1117, 1118, 1119};

    // duel list, PID <> PID
    std::vector <DWORD, DWORD> m_vec_duelList;
```

I want to make a randomized vector pair (DWORD, DWORD) from another vector (DWORD)  and iterate the paired one (duel list). In above example there are **9 player ID**'s. I want to make randomized pair these 8 players and leave the unpaired one in first vector **(for later pairing; 'next round')** and delete **these 8 player ID's** from first vector. As far as I know; **std::make_pair** and to get next element in vector **std::next** in C++11 but I'm so confused, it seems there are many ways to do this job but I couldn't find any reliable answer related to my question. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Start with `std::vector<std::pair<DWORD, DWORD>> m_vec_duelList`

Comment: the problem is getting the first element then pairing with next one..

Comment: The next thing is to think about how you'd write a loop that could access one element in a vector, as well as the next one. Ensure that you don't step out of bounds. Ensure that the vector has an "appropriate" number of elements.

Comment: yes, for "appropriate" number, that's why I noticed that I want to leave the unpaired PID and leave for next pairing (aka next round, in game.) I hope some one answers

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you should begin by creating a copy of your original vector (if you still need it) and randomly shuffling it:

```
auto atten_rand = m_vec_attender;
std::shuffle(atten_rand.begin(), atten_rand.end());
```

Having randomly shuffled it, you can now just pair them sequentially. Your target vector should be declared as:

```
std::vector<std::pair<DWORD, DWORD>> m_vec_duelList;
```

And now you can do:

```
for (int i = 0; i != 4; ++i) {
    m_vec_duelList.emplace_back(atten_rand[2*i], atten_rand[2*i+1]);
}
```

Note that by default, `std::shuffle` usually uses `rand` underlying for randomness, which is not a very high quality random number generator. This is probably fine to quickly generate a draw but if you have higher randomness needs you should investigate that in more detail.

Comment: thank you so much for interesting in my question as first. In your answer what happens to the unpaired one?

Comment: @noname005 Nothing happens to it per se. As you can see from the code, since it's traversing the randomized list from the beginning, the unpaired elements will simply be the last element of the randomized list. So you can access/view it with `atten_rand.back()`.

Comment: and is it possible to reach this answer without c++11 ?

Comment: in addition; I have more than 8 ID's in first PID vector, I just gave an example for 9 PIDs

Comment: for (int i = 0; i != 4; ++i)
 {
  m_vec_duelList.push_back({ m_vec_attender[2 * i], m_vec_attender[2 * i + 1] });
 }

this is as far as I get about my problem

Comment: @noname005: There is (deprecated) `std::random_shuffle` pre c++11.

Comment: @noname005 Get rid of the braces in `emplace_back()`'s parameter list, and it should work.  `m_vec_duelList.emplace_back(atten_rand[2*i], atten_rand[2*i+1]);`  Alternatively, use `push_back()`: `m_vec_duelList.push_back({atten_rand[2*i], atten_rand[2*i+1]});`.  [That should solve the error you got.](http://rextester.com/SNXQ70199)

Comment: Hello, right now I have this: http://prntscr.com/dwh8cr but problem is what can I do if get any odd number.. I want to clear the m_vec_attender vector and only leave the unpaired one in the vector.